# PHP MySQL Select a SUM minus a SUM

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a query like below:

```
SELECT (SUM(amount) - SUM(refundAmount)) as amount FROM orders WHERE $invoiceFilter AND $websiteFilter
```

It's getting the sum of the amount column correctly, but it's not subtracting out the refund amount.

What is the correct syntax for a query like this?

Comment: This should be correct, provide some sample data and your desired result will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount - refundAmount) AS `amount` 
FROM orders 
WHERE 
    invoice = $invoiceFilter 
    AND website = $websiteFilter;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

SQL:

```
SELECT amount - refund
FROM (SELECT SUM(amount) as amount
      FROM orders
      WHERE invoice = 'invoiceFilter' AND website = 'websiteFilter') as a,
     (SELECT SUM(refundAmount) as refund
      FROM orders
      WHERE invoice = 'invoiceFilter' AND website = 'websiteFilter') as b;
```

PHP:

```
mysql_query("SELECT amount - refund
             FROM (SELECT SUM(amount) as amount
                   FROM orders
                   WHERE invoice = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($invoiceFilter). "'
                   AND website = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($websiteFilter). "') as a,
                  (SELECT SUM(refundAmount) as refund
                   FROM orders
                   WHERE invoice = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($invoiceFilter). "'
                   AND website = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($websiteFilter). "') as b; ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You maybe missing something like a reference column to filter the data you need to process. Something like:

```
SELECT (SUM(amount) - SUM(refundAmount)) AS amount 
FROM orders 
WHERE 
    <a_column> = $invoiceFilter 
    AND <another_column> = $websiteFilter;
```